# Animate UITableViewCell height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a container view inside a UITableViewCell which is attached to the 4 edges of the contentview with a padding. I can resize the containerView by pinching changing the height and padding. All the constraints update correctly but the contentView height doesn't change. Here are the constraints of the containerView.

```
contentView.addSubview(containerView)

containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
containerViewLeadingAnchor =
containerView.leadingAnchor                 .constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor,                         constant: 10)
containerViewTopAnchor =
containerView.topAnchor                     .constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor,                             constant: 10)
containerViewBottomAnchor =
containerView.bottomAnchor                  .constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor,                          constant: -10)
containerViewHeightAnchor =
containerView.heightAnchor                  .constraint(equalToConstant: 146)
containerViewWidthAnchor =
containerView.widthAnchor                   .constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 20)

containerViewLeadingAnchor.isActive = true
containerViewTopAnchor.isActive = true
containerViewBottomAnchor.isActive = true
containerViewHeightAnchor.isActive = true
containerViewWidthAnchor.isActive = true
```

And here is how i update them inside the UITableViewCell

```
containerViewLeadingAnchor.constant     = containerPaddingForComfortable - (containerPaddingForComfortable * scaleRatio)
containerViewTopAnchor.constant         = containerPaddingForComfortable - (containerPaddingForComfortable * scaleRatio)
containerViewWidthAnchor.constant       = (UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 20) + (containerPaddingForComfortable*2 * scaleRatio)
containerViewBottomAnchor.constant      = -containerPaddingForComfortable + (containerPaddingForComfortable * scaleRatio)

containerView.layer.cornerRadius = containerCornerRadius - (containerCornerRadius * scaleRatio)
self.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: Did you check how to resize table view cell? A content view is controlled by cell which is controlled by table view. In most cases all you need to do is call `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()` on the table view to refresh visible cell positions and sizes. But in your case you might want to avoid table view. Maybe stack view on scroll view would be more appropriate. Or just a view in scroll view.

Comment: beginUpdates() and endUpdates() did he trick. Thank you. :)

In my excitement i actually clicked the update button more than once and now i can't being back the upvote. Sorry. :x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not enough to simply modify view frame or constraints to update the size of content view.

In table view the cell content view is controlled by cell which is controlled by table view or rather it's data source or delegate. In your case you need to have cell height set to automatic dimensions so constraints are used internally to determine cell size. Once that is done you will need to call `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()` on the table view. So something like:

```
func resizeMyCell(_ cell: MyCell, to height: CGFloat) {
    cell.heightConstraint.constant = height
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Although it might seem strange the two calls will invalidate sizes and refresh table view cell sizes and positions. By the way changing cell size usually means also moving rest of the cells beneath the resized one.